# Cannot get a data from Realm object Server in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I wanted to share data between smartphones using the Realm Object Server and I made this code with Swift.
(I using Realm -> 3.0.2 ROS -> latest)

```
let realmAuthURL = URL(string:"http://[server_address]:9080")!
let realmURL = URL(string:"realm://[server_address]:9080/~/realm")!
let credentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: "[username]", password: "[password]")

SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: realmAuthURL) { user, error in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let user = user {
            Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
                syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: realmURL),
                objectTypes: [PCData.self]
            )
            print("ログインに成功しました")
            self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration)
            //print(self.realm.objects(PCData.self))

            if self.realm.isEmpty {
                try! self.realm.write {
                    let data = PCData()
                    data.isOut = false
                    data.pcCode = "***METADATA***"
                    data.rentPCto = ""
                    data.IDinCourse = 999999999999
                    data.belonging = "Master"

                    self.realm.add(data)
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

When I tried it, "ログインに成功しました" was output, and the server has logs that seemed to have been accessed

However,

```
2017-12-17 22:53:30.880875+0900 PCManage[7021:1784833] Sync: Connection[1]: Connection closed due to error
2017-12-17 22:53:31.673562+0900 PCManage[7021:1784833] Sync: Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '[Server's IP]:9080' (from '[My IP]:57032')
2017-12-17 22:53:31.684189+0900 PCManage[7021:1784833] Sync: Connection[1]: Writing failed: End of input
```

it is not possible to get data etc.
In Server.

```
proxy: attempting to upgrade client [My IP]:57032 => headers: {"authorization":"Realm-Access-Token version=1 token=\"eyJhY2Nlc3MiOlsiZG93bmxvYWQiLCJ1cGxvYWQiLCJtYW5hZ2UiXSwiYXBwX2lkIjoiY29tLmFrYmFydC5hcHAuUVJ0ZXN0IiwiZXhwaXJlcyI6MTUxMzUxOTQwOCwiaWQiOiIwMzdmY2I5Yzc0MGE0ZjdhOGVhOTZkZmFhYjUxNmM2ZiIsImlkZW50aXR5IjoiZmI0NmQ1ZjNjYjRiNmE5NWExYWYyNDkzZGIxNjE5YzYiLCJwYXRoIjoiL2ZiNDZkNWYzY2I0YjZhOTVhMWFmMjQ5M2RiMTYxOWM2L3JlYWxtIn0=:Tn4Qa4vzvZ87lnW2htmt6rPCaLL5ASDkpqbcXT2eKskQ3NHJ3ePyMxvJjjyAq5rh8pb2syCM1Dh8LrVk9RilQsHwHRU9HyDOky/psePE4UfXidEJGYoML19R9mo+yjHPG7DeP0ykYltTjONJh+OpQkaelHYIMlKAwFP+hxeNWlVAIpjohkqmyr/de3++8IxcVV6/6wJUESdNpDq2e5GGKfxpSwbfhBagNi0m0aSNuwzoqJ5CFqbyoxsyyCZWx6XJ7ZueTmRvGx22SJcthRzxrQRrWMbMtF8yEHY/AARzycO/A/Zi5spXqAzQD6QIrkl5gGI/FwvnLvhvtPEFychXIg==\"","connection":"Upgrade","host":"[]","sec-websocket-key":"K0Tw7zhY3ov9h+VEqHtaPQ==","sec-websocket-protocol":"io.realm.sync.22","sec-websocket-version":"13","upgrade":"websocket"}.}
sync: HTTP Connection[959]: Connection from 127.0.0.1:35414
sync: HTTP Connection[959]: Connection initiates HTTP receipt
sync: HTTP Connection[959]: HTTP request received, url = /realm-sync/%2Ffb46d5f3cb4b6a95a1af2493db1619c6%2Frealm
sync: HTTP Connection[959]: 404 Not Found
sync: HTTP Connection[959]: Connection is closed after HTTP response.
```

404 Not Fount displayed
I think that the server side is strange right now, but I have not changed from the initial setting, so I do not know where is wrong
How can I get the data?

Comment: When you're providing versions of software, please specify the precise versions you're using. "latest" is typically just misleading, and often indicates the latest version is _not_ being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log messages that you've shared appear to indicate that you're using Realm Object Server v1.x. Realm Swift 3.x requires Realm Object Server v2.x. See the [Realm Object Server documentation](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/) for instructions on installing ROS v2.x.